# Change asynchronously coming data in angular direcitve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have directive:

```
angular.module('mymodule').directive('someName', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            headerId: '=header',
            data: '=data'
        },
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        compile: function() {
            return function($scope, $link, $attr) {
                console.log($scope.headerId); // print actual header id
                console.log($scope.data);     // undefined

        /* ... code ... */
```

The point is header is hardcoded as number in directive attribute. And everything fine with it. But data is got from server with angular service asynchronously. So at the moment when compile function runs there is no data in $scope. My problem is that I want to change data so that it will be readable by directive template.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add watcher to data
scope.$watch('data', function() {...})